# Is it correct to say "go to the bike park" or "go to the motorbike park" instead of "go to the car park"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

**outdoor motorbike park**

[image]

**underground motorbike park**

A place is used for parking mostly motorbikes or bicycles, sometimes some small cars, and it can be outdoors or underground.

Is it correct to say "**go to the bike park**" or "**go to the motorbike park**" instead of "**go to the car park**"?

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense but I think you should treat this as a new word and use some scare quotes.

> John realised that there was an opportunity to start a "motorbike park", to provide parking for the many bikers that used the area.

The scare quotes warn the reader that they should interpret this as a new word, and so understand it from context.

Comment: Maybe, "go to the parking area"? is it correct to to say that?